# Calculating daily returns

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am currently trying to calculate daily returns for "WMK", "DIS", "PEP", and I cannot get the right code to do so. As well as this I need to plot the returns as well. Could someone please help me, I will attach code below.

```
prices= tq_get("WMK", "DIS", "PEP", from = "2000-01-01", to = "2022-06-01")
  
R.WMK= Return.calculate(xts(prices), method="discrete")
R.DIS= Return.calculate(xts(prices), method="discrete")
R.PEP= Return.calculate(xts(prices), method="discrete")

ggplot(R.WMK, type = "1")
ggplot(R.DIS, type = "1")
ggplot(R.PEP, type ="1")
```

Comment: Have you read the vignettes that are available for tidyquant? There are examples in those that you can adjust to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get the % daily return on adjusted prices:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(scales)

price_df <- tq_get(c("WMK", "DIS", "PEP"), 
                 from = "2000-01-01", to = "2022-06-01")

return_df <- price_df |> 
  group_by(symbol) |> 
  mutate(daily_return = adjusted / lag(adjusted) - 1)

return_df |> 
  ggplot(aes(symbol, daily_return)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_percent())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Daily simple return

```
tq_get(c("WMK", "DIS", "PEP"), from = "2000-01-01", 
       to = "2022-06-01") %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%  
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted, 
            mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
            period = "daily", 
            col_rename = "return") %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = date, y = return, col = symbol) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~ symbol)
```

[image: Simple return]

Cumulative return

```
tq_get(c("WMK", "DIS", "PEP"), from = "2000-01-01", 
       to = "2022-06-01") %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%  
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted, 
            mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
            period = "daily", 
            col_rename = "return") %>%  
  mutate(cr = cumprod(1 + return)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = date, y = cr, col = symbol) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ symbol)
```

[image: Cumulative return]

Descriptive table

```
library(e1071)

df <- tq_get(c("WMK", "DIS", "PEP"), from = "2000-01-01", 
       to = "2022-06-01") %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%  
  tq_mutate(select = adjusted, 
            mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
            period = "daily", 
            col_rename = "return") %>%  
  mutate(cr = cumprod(1 + return)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(return), 
            median = median(return), 
            variance = var(return), 
            deviation = sd(return), 
            skewness = skewness(return),
            kurtosis = kurtosis(return))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  symbol     mean   median variance deviation skewness kurtosis
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 DIS    0.000464 0.000334 0.000374    0.0193    0.346     9.60
2 PEP    0.000447 0.000332 0.000163    0.0128    0.181    15.3 
3 WMK    0.000376 0.000202 0.000302    0.0174    0.125     6.80
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain once again, but my document won't knit now. With the deadline of 11:59pm AWST. Is there any chance you could help me.